# How to encrypt the user input(for ex : password) in java output console

Tags: java

**Uses Case :**
My objective is whenever user tries to give user input (for ex: password) in console output screen instead of password text (For ex in output console : Enter the password :******** (but the password is Qwerty@123,but when user types Qwerty@123 it should get replaced by ********* in console)), astericks should get displayed.Is it possible to do,i have seen some video as well based on password encryption in java but did'nt found anything related to my question.

```
import java.util.*;

public class abc {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String g;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the password : ");
        g = sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Output i am getting:
Enter the password : Qwerty@123

Output what i am excepting:
Enter the password : ********** should get typed while user types Qwerty@123

Please let me know if question asked is not a clear.
Thanks in advance, be safe!!

Comment: get the length of g string and print * for that number of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDK provides `Console` class to handle these scenarios, it provides [readPassword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) to read password by masking, it doesn't display *'s though.

Here is a small example.

```
import java.io.Console;
public class Library {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Console console = System.console();
    char[] passwordArray = console.readPassword("Enter your password: ");
    console.printf("Password is: %s%n", new String(passwordArray));
}
}
```

**Note: This only works with System's console, doesn't work with IDE.**

Comment: This will not run on `IDE` I think. You need to run it on `Console`

Comment: @kedarsedai Right, edited the answer.